# 'ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I run this code, the following error occurs

> ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Code:

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Products where ProductName like('%" + Request.QueryString["search"].ToString() + "%')";
}

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

dlProduct.DataSource = dt;
dlProduct.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: btw; there's no purpose use use in running `ExecuteNonQuery` - that **doesn't fetch your results**

Answer (score 3):

This would happen if you didn't have a `search` query-string parameter - you would never assign to `CommandText`.

However: *please please please* never write code like this; this is a SQL Injection hole that would let anyone own your database trivially. Please use ADO.NET parameters, or data access tools that do it for you.

Example:

```
string q = Request.QueryString["search"] ?? "";
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Products where ProductName like N'%' + @q + N'%'";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", q);
```

Also: the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` does nothing useful - so just throw that away.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting CommandText conditionally and the condition is false thats why you are getting error. Ensure you have search in querystring and also use parameterized query instead of embedding the value in queries to prevent sql injection

```
  if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Products where ProductName like('%" + Request.QueryString["search"].ToString() + "%')";
        }
```